# Data type issue when using Java library in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have found a nice Java library for linear algebra, named [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)

In Java, I can use such library by writing:

```
double[N][M] mat;
for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
  for (int c = 0; c < M; c++)
    mat[r][c] = ...;

Matrix A = new Matrix(mat);
```

I would like to use the same library inside a Scala program.

I need to use the `double[][]` data type, in order to pass it to the `Matrix` constructor. How can I express such data type in Scala?

Thank you

Comment: [Array.ofDim](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html)? And, this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7254546/205936)

Comment: You may also want to consider a Scala library such as Breeze: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Breeze-Linear-Algebra